# Introductory Book on Faltings' Proof of the Mordell Conjecture

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry

I'm currently reading Diamond and Shurman's book a First Course in Modular Forms and I've found it to be a wonderful introduction to the modularity theorem. Is there a similar introductory book for Faltings' proof of the Mordell conjecture?

All I've found so far are articles by Bloch and Mazur and while they give a good introduction of the ideas involved I'm looking for something with a little more detail, yet still friendly to beginners, preferably analogous to Diamond and Shurman or even the more introductory book of Hellegouarch on Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: You should take a look [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/202675/understanding-faltingss-theorem)

Comment: These notes might be useful http://math.stanford.edu/~akshay/ntslearn.html

Comment: Another thing to recommend is Cornell-Silverman. Happily this is back in print again. http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387963112 I think it's similar in spirit to the Cornell-Silverman-Stevens book: in principle, everything needed for Faltings' paper is there and an English translation of Faltings is given.

Comment: [I won't claim this is as friendly as Diamond-Shurman, but IIRC DS don't get close to actually proving a modularity theorem.]